# Bind onPress function to a <Text> view

Tags: react-native

I want to bind onPress event to a part of a Text view without using TouchableOpacity or TouchableHighlight because they break text with new lines.

is there any way to bind it directly to the Text element in React-native?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import { View, Text, Alert} from 'react-native';

export default class SliderContainer extends Component {
  
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{marginTop: 50}}>
       <Text>
        {`TextPartOne
        `}
        <Text onPress={() => Alert.alert(
  'Alert Title',
  'My Alert Msg',
  [
    {text: 'Ask me later', onPress: () => console.log('Ask me later pressed')},
    {text: 'Cancel', onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'), style: 'cancel'},
    {text: 'OK', onPress: () => console.log('OK Pressed')},
  ],
  { cancelable: false }
)}>
            {`Nested text to press`}
        </Text>
        {`
        TextPartTwo`}
    </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

You could try [this snack](https://snack.expo.io/H1IAxxhtM).

Comment: Ok, but the problem appears with nested Texts, and i need it to be nested so as to bind event to just a part of the Text