# Get the time that no actions on app

Tags: javascript, react-native

I need to show a message in my app if the user does not tap or do any action on it. Example:

```
if (timeNoAction = 15s){
  alert('tap')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [PanResponder](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/panresponder.html) :

Here is code example:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button, PanResponder, View, StyleSheet,TouchableOpacity, Text , Image, Alert} from 'react-native';

const timeNoAction = 15000;

export default class Screen extends Component {
  state = {
    show : false
  };
  _panResponder = {};
  timer = 0;
  componentWillMount() {
    this._panResponder = PanResponder.create({

      onStartShouldSetPanResponder: () => {
        this.resetTimer()
        return true
      },
      onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: () => true,
      onStartShouldSetPanResponderCapture: () => { this.resetTimer() ; return false},
      onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture: () => false,
      onPanResponderTerminationRequest: () => true,
      onShouldBlockNativeResponder: () => false,
    });
    this.timer = setTimeout(()=>this.setState({show:true}),timeNoAction )
  }

  resetTimer(){
    clearTimeout(this.timer)
    if(this.state.show)
    this.setState({show:false})
    this.timer = setTimeout(()=>this.setState({show:true}),timeNoAction )
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View
        style={styles.container}
        collapsable={false}
        {...this._panResponder.panHandlers}>

        {
          this.state.show ? Alert.alert(
            'Alert',
            'You have been inactive for 15sec',
            [
              {text: 'OK', onPress: () => this.resetTimer()},
            ],
            { cancelable: false }
          ) : null
        }
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
  }
});

}
```

You could use it in any component or in the whole app by setting it in App.js

source: [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49344678/bind-onpress-function-to-a-text-view/49347940#49347940)

Comment: Exists a bug: I have 5 screens, so I put this code on first screen, but when I navigate to other screen, the time of first screen continuos counting and show the alert

Comment: Nice catch!, you could overcome this issue  by removing the timer in `componentWillUnmount` method.
I think this would be something like this:
`this._panResponder ={};`
OR
`clearTimeout(this.timer)`

Comment: I code `componentWillUnmount(){ this._panResponder ={}; clearTimeout(this.timer); }` but its not working :/

Answer (score 1):

Use [react-native-interaction-provider](https://github.com/robinpowered/react-native-interaction-provider)

It is a behavioral component wrapper detecting user interactions, and letting you know when the application has idled.

```
import InteractionProvider from 'react-native-interaction-provider'

    <InteractionProvider
      timeout={15 * 1000} // idle after 15s
      onActive={() => console.log('User no longer idle')}
      onInactive={() => console.log('User is idle for 15s')}
    >
      <YourScreen />
    </InteractionProvider>
```